# How to show code blocks for programming snippets in Django Summernote?

Tags: django, summernote

I am using Django Summernote on my [website](https://www.notemaker.in). This is how the editor looks.
[image]
Below you can find the django settings for my Summernote editor.

```
SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG = {
    # Or, you can set it as False to use SummernoteInplaceWidget by default - no iframe mode
    # In this case, you have to load Bootstrap/jQuery stuff by manually.
    # Use this when you're already using Bootstraip/jQuery based themes.
    'iframe': False,

    # You can put custom Summernote settings
    'summernote': {
        # As an example, using Summernote Air-mode
        'airMode': False,

        # Change editor size
        'width': '100%',
        'height': '480',

        'toolbar': [
            ['style', ['style']],
            ['font', ['bold', 'underline', 'clear']],
            ['fontname', ['fontname']],
            ['color', ['color']],
            ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
            ['table', ['table']],
            ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'video']],
            ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview', 'help']],
        ],

        

        'codemirror': {
            'mode': 'htmlmixed',
            'lineNumbers': 'true',
            # You have to include theme file in 'css' or 'css_for_inplace' before using it.
            'theme': 'monokai',
        },

    }
}
```

But sadly, it doesn't have the option for a **Code block** to show programming snippets. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, you have to swith (degrade) to bootstrap 3 in your settings.py file :

```
    SUMMERNOTE_THEME = 'bs3'
```

I don't know why bs4 don't have that built in style. If you insist on using bs4, you have to use an external plugin with django summernote and edit the summernote config like this in your settings.py again :

```
SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG = { 
    
    'summernote' : {
        'width': '100%',
        'height': '720',

    'codemirror': {
        'mode': 'htmlmixed',
        'lineNumbers': 'true',
}
}
}
```

this example is for using codemirror external plugin with summernote (and changing the size of the field)

Answer (score 0):

[Django Summernote](https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote) already has a built in code format

[image: django summernote]

Try reinstalling django summernote in your django project and make sure you got all the setup instructions stated right in their [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote)

Answer (score 0):

all of the above solutions are not working as expected, I added new set of CSS and jquery code and working as expected-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.20/dist/summernote-lite.min.css" integrity="sha256-IKhQVXDfwbVELwiR0ke6dX+pJt0RSmWky3WB2pNx9Hg=" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.20/dist/summernote-lite.min.js" integrity="sha256-5slxYrL5Ct3mhMAp/dgnb5JSnTYMtkr4dHby34N10qw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Now, fonts, dropdowns and other functionalities working correctly